# Want to auto sort a Google sheets spreadsheet on edit, but want to sort by date

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, columnsorting

Been looking around for a solution to this for a while and not finding anything that works, unfortunately.  I have tried copying and pasting several bits of code but cannot get my sales pipeline sheet to automatically sort on edit of a date field.

The link below is to a test sheet which should give an idea as to how I have formatted my sheet:

https://docs.google.com/a/trinitymirror.com/spreadsheets/d/1huTvgwfmh0RM0kz4BUEuYFZm7DwBG-69D8jTfps3IPg/edit?usp=sharing

I want to sort by Column G with the most recent dates at the bottom of the sheet.

Any suggestions welcome!

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/14265/188352

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should help?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:Z450");

 // Sorts by the values in column 2 (B)
 range.sort({column: 2, ascending: false});
  
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but although that works on the test sheet when I copy it to the spreadsheet I am working on, it doesn't sort.  Also, how can I sort it so that it doesn't affect the header?  BTW I have Triggers on, current set to onEdit - on spreadsheet - onedit.  Thank you

Comment: are you working on the first sheet- indicated by the getsheets()[0] - you could try to use get sheet by name instead. change the range to A2:Z999

Comment: Yes I am working on the first sheets.  Also after changing the range to A2:Z999 I get an error message: Service Error: Spreadsheets

Comment: Received this error: TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 4, file "Code")

Comment: Changed Sheets1 to Pipeline which is the name of the sheet, and now i get this error again: Service error: SpreadsheetsDismiss

Comment: do you have less then 450 rows? try to decrease this number

Comment: That's worked thank you! And what do I add if I want it Ascending rather than descending?

Comment: you will want to change the sheet title and the row number to a smaller number as you did before.

Comment: Ignore that, I changed the range to a lesser amount again. Changed to Y200.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I have realised that as soon as I delete a row, the range needs modifying.  Is there anyway to edit the range so that it automatically updates should I delete a row?